# How to replace slashes with a space

Tags: bash

I'm trying to replace slashes with a space:

```
category='dir1/dir2/dir3'
category="${category//\// /}"
echo $category
dir1 /dir2 /dir3
```

I'd like to get `dir1 dir2 dir3`.

How can I get this using Bash?

Comment: Just remove the last `/` from `"${category//\// /}"`. Like this: `category="${category//\// }"`

Comment: It is far too easy to confuse `sed`'s `s/this/that/g` with `bash`'s `${var//this/that}` if you don't use both in roughly equal measure, I have found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "replace all" syntax in `bash` is `${variable//OLD/NEW}`, with no trailing slash. The slash you have there right now is considered part of the replacement, so you're replacing each slash with space-slash, not just with a space. Remove the final slash to get what you want:

```
$ category='dir1/dir2/dir3'
$ category="${category//\// }"
$ echo "$category"
dir1 dir2 dir3
```

Comment: Note that that syntax comes from ksh93. `${var//OLD/}` (to replace with nothing) can also be written `${var//OLD}`. See also the `$var:s/old/new/` of csh which predates ksh's by decades and is much closer to `ed`'s `s/re/new/`. Also supported by zsh but not by bash even though bash copied csh history expansion. For *global* subst, you need `:as/old/new/` in tcsh and `:gs/old/new/` in zsh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas interesting! What's old is new again. Presumably with tcsh's `:as` in the construct `:as/old/new/`, the `a` stands for all? Raku is using something similar to the zsh construct to represent substitute:global  -- the Raku version is `s:g/old/new/`.